# How to accurately position divs with css

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm sure this is super simple, but I'm new to css. I'm essentially trying to position some rendered typography and make it stay centred no matter what the size of the browser is. I've tried using margins with percents, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code.

html

```
<div class="weare">
    <img src="image/textrenders/weare.png" />
</div>
<div class="shaftesburytv">
    <img src="image/textrenders/Shaftesburytv.png" />
</div>
<div class="awebbasedstudio">
    <img src="image/textrenders/awebbasedstudio.png" />
</div>
```

css

```
.weare {}

.shaftesburytv {}

.awebbasedstudio {}
```

I want the result to look something [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxW4C9zeoabxcnVsQWkyV3Jwc1E/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto:`

Comment: You want to align it horizontally or/and vertically? Horizontally, as agconti said, `margin: 0 auto;` will center it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify your content:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/50">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/75">
</div>
```

Then ensure the container has the same width as the largest contained image, and apply `margin:0 auto;` to it to center. Finally put `display:block` on the images to make them all stack vertically:

```
#container {
    margin:100px auto;
    width:300px;
}
#container img {
    display:block;
}
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/69Eb2/).

Alternatively, if you also want to center vertically, you can also use absolute positioning and then negative margins on the absolute size of the object - no problem for you since the image sizes are fixed:

```
#container {
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-112px;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
#container img {
    display:block;
}
```

[Sample of this approach here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/Ven63/).

Comment: I'd like to leave a note that you never close your `image` tags.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ven63/1/) is a fixed version of your **fiddle.**

Comment: @ManofSnow why would I? The [HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html) specifically states it's a [void element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element), making it self-closing by definition. Only XHTML ever required tags like `<br />` and `<img />` to be closed because it was compatible with XML - HTML5 is an SGML subset instead where it is allowed to self-close, but advised not to.

Comment: Great!  Just because it's not required, don't do it

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding me. SGML, and as such HTML5, only supports self-closing tags for *backwards compatibility* with XHTML. It is *recommended* and *intended* to **not self-close** any void tags.

Comment: [Read this article](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/).

Comment: No, I get you.  HTML5 doesn't support it (I looked it up right after you commented 'No, you're misunderstanding me'

Comment: Well there's the matter of terminology. HTML5 validators *accept* self-closing void tags, and the specs mention that you are allowed to do it, so technically it is *supported*. It is however not the recommended notation.

Comment: The precise statement in the standards is [here under item 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-start-tags) btw.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now ;)

Comment: Not rubbing anything in, just sharing knowledge, and I was also curious where *exactly* it was in the specs hehe  :)

Comment: **+1** I almost forgot; you seem like you spent time on this answer, with a minor edit only, *and* you simplified his code.  I would've rushed to get the first answer (I did :P)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using *images,* you could

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to them.  For text, you could

`text-align:center;`

With `div`s, you could also `center align` them (in HTML).

You could also use `center` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/A33J2/

Comment: hmm. Doesn't seem to work... Would I put this on a body or the individual divs?

Comment: @DarrenPlace Try setting `align` to `center` in the HTML?

Comment: @DarrenPlace Try using `center` tags or setting `align` to `center`?

Comment: That works... but I'm trying to set up the pixel cropped images in the layout of the example I've posted

Answer (score 0):

It can be verry simple.

If you do not split your image and gather all text of it into one.

html

```
<img id="my-whole-image" src="http://placekitten.com/300/250" />
```

css

```
#my-whole-image {
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-125px;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    display:block;
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/x298N/)

Just a tip, ence you're saying you are new to css, i presume you are new to html too : always use the minimum required to build your webpages. Those 3 images **had** to be merged into one for many reasons like server request, bandwidth, browser redraw, dom elements number.